# Created a Whatsapp group, then left did not get message to delete group

Tags: settings

I created a group messing with phone, added half a dozen names then went to cancel it, I was removed from group but did not get the following message asking if I wanted to cancel it,  the group was called Lookers, I had not realised it would be so easy to create and I would have thought each member would need to accept membership to a new group, I have looked online how to delete this to no avail, as I have left it no longer appears on my phone, this has caused me much embarrassment and I need this group to be cancelled it was created on Wednesday 14 June I Do not even have all the names of members.

Answer (score 0):

If you were the only group admin and you exit a group, a participant is chosen at random to become the new admin<sup>1</sup>. The new admin can then remove each user individually or the rest of the users can voluntarily leave the group like you did. You cannot do much at this point since you are no longer an admin in the group.

---

<sup>1. https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/s60/23721933#exit</sup>